# How do I block certain domain requests via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a client side javascript that prevents other 3rd party scripts requesting  certain domain urls on their own. Is there a way to achieve this?

Example setup:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript>
    <script src="third-party-script.js" type="text/javascript>
  </body>
</html>
```

now `third-party-script.js` requests from the domain `www.track-me.com`, i want to be able to block  outgoing track-me.com requests via code inside `myscript.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to intercept network requests from your page and handle them as you please.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention i need it to work on  IE11